# fibonacci sequence in mips and storing result in 2 registers

Tags: assembly, mips, 32-bit

i wrote a Fibonacci program in mips and the max Int it will go up to is **1836311903** as its being stored in a $t3 register .

I read that its possible to go beyond this my using 2 registers to store the fib values .

Heres how my code look for the fib sequence and the max term it goes up to is 44 .

```
    .data 
fib:.word
    .text
    .globl  main
main:

    # The loop
        li      $t2, 1                  # Initialize f_old to 1
        li      $t1, 0                  # Initialize f_older to 0
        li      $t4, 2                  # Initialize counter i to 2
        li  $t0 ,0          #This is the n in fib(n)
        la  $s0,fib
        li  $t9 , 44   #this is the max value of n that can be stored in 32bit , anything greater causes overflow.
lp_tst: blt    $t9, $t0, done          # If $t4 > $t0 (i >  n), 
                                        #    branch out of loop.
                                        #    Otherwise continue.
        add     $t3, $t2, $t1           # Add f_old to f_older
        move    $t1, $t2                # Replace f_older with f_old
        move    $t2, $t3                # Replace f_old with f_new

    sw  $t2 , 0($s0)

        addi    $t4, $t4, 1             # Increment i (i++)
        addi    $t0,$t0,1
        j       lp_tst                  # Go to the loop test

        # Done with the loop, print result
done:   li      $v0, 1                  # Code to print an int
        move    $a0, $t2                # Put f_old in $a0
        syscall                         # Print the string


        li      $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Any ideas on how to store the value in multiple registers to allow it to store 64 bit ints?

*THANKS*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the 64-bit `f_old` is in `$t2:$t1` and `f_older` is in `$t4:$t3`:

```
addu  $t5, $t1, $t3    # f_new.lo = f_old.lo + f_older.lo 
sltu  $t0, $t5, $t1    # set "carry" in $t0 if f_new.lo < f_old.lo  
addu  $t0, $t0, $t4    # f_older.hi + carry
addu  $t6, $t0, $t2    # f_new.hi = f_old.hi + f_older.hi + carry
```

Now the 64-bit `f_new` is in `$t6:$t5`.

Comment: f_old is only a 32 bit register

Comment: The answer is storing a 64 bit number in two 32 bit registers: '($t6:$t5)'.

Comment: If you're going to have a 64-bit `f_new` you'll need `f_old` and `f_older` to be 64-bit as well. Otherwise you won't be able to do the step where you set `f_older = f_old` and `f_old = f_new`.

Comment: @Michael implementing this didn't seem to work when i put it in my code

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you did it's hard to say what the problem might be. I got the expected result from my example code when running some quick tests in SPIM.

Comment: @Michael sorry  i got it :D
Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

If using 32 bit unsigned integers, then fib(47) can be calculated. You can eliminate usage of some of the registers and shorten up the code with something like the code below. I haven't checked the code since I don't have a mips board or mips simulator and I don't know which version you're using.

```
        li      $t9,47          #max value for n
#fibonacci code                 #i = 0 (for comments only, not in code)
        li      $t1,0           #if n odd, t1 = 0 = fib( 0)
        andi    $t0,$t9,1       #          t0 = 1 = fib(-1)
        bgtz    $t0,fib1        #br if n odd
        li      $t1,1           #if n even, t0 = 0, t1 = 1
        j       fib2            #br to check for n == 0
fib0:   add     $t1,$t1,$t0     #i++, fib(i-2) += fib(i-1), t1 = fib(i)
fib1:   add     $t0,$t0,$t1     #i++, fib(i-2) += fib(i-1), t0 = fib(i)
fib2:   subi    $t9,$t9,2       #loop if not done
        bgez    $t9,fib0
                                #result in t0
```